# btrfs check / scrub: what is the difference?

Tags: usb, backup, btrfs

I am going to use (for now) btrfs on a couple of external USB HDD archives, in single-mode (no DUP, no RAID, no nothing; I will just keep it simple for now). So my idea is that I have two (manually copied) identical copies of an archive on two separate btrfs USB HDDs, one being the main where I change the archive and sometimes copy all the changed stuff to the other USB HDD.

The reason I want to use btrfs is merely that I can easily check at any time whether the all files on the main archive ok, and if not, I can copy those files back from the other HDD, manually. So I presume I will use btrfs scrub for finding the errors, and then e.g.
[Finding files with BTRFS Uncorrectable Errors](https://superuser.com/questions/858237/finding-files-with-btrfs-uncorrectable-errors)
to find which files have those errors and need to be replaced from the backup.

However, I also see there is a "btrfs check" command as well. Reading both scrub and check manual pages, it wasn't clear to me what the difference is and what their exact purpose is.

So if I just want to see whether my btrfs volume's files are ok with no errors and bitrot and corruption, am I supposed to run both check and scrub, or is mere scrub enough?

Comment: [`btrfs check`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-check) seems to verify and optionally attempt repair of the structure of the filesystem.  [`btrfs scrub`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-scrub) verifies (and possibly repairs) the checksums of every data and metadata block.

Comment: So I gather then that both should be normally run, one after another? Probably check first...

Comment: I'm not sure either **directly** addresses your desire to insure each file is uncorrupted.  Files are stored in blocks (checked by `scrub`) and blocks make up the structure of the btrfs filesystem (checked by `check`).  I'm wondering why you don't want to configure btrfs to use some redundancy automatically (DUP, RAID) rather than doing it manually yourself.

Comment: Yes I have understood scrub does not tell directly which files are affected, only that there errors. However, I had a link in my question to how to find the affected files.
I am not using DUP or RAID for now because then I would need more hard drives to keep the same amount of data and keep the same level of redundancy. For instance if I use DUP, then I can keep only half of my data on one hard drive, and divide my data between them. In that case I lose half of my data if either USB HDD gets broken or lost. OTOH if I use RAID, then I need to connect both hard drives if I need some files.

Comment: Also, I am not yet fully sure if I will use btrfs with both hard drives (archives). It depends how well WinBtrfs works ie. if I can at least read the archive files also in Windows. If not, I'll probably keep the secondary archive with NTFS, and the primary with BTRFS. Then I just from time to time "rsync -avzc --delete" everything from the primary BRTFS archive HDD to the secondary (NTFS or BTRFS) archive HDD, and use that on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rickhg12s in the comments had the right answer:

"btrfs check seems to verify and optionally attempt repair of the structure of the filesystem. btrfs scrub verifies (and possibly repairs) the checksums of every data and metadata block."